# Is there a way to checkout a branch whose name starts with foo?

Tags: git

In my organization, we use user story IDs to name our branches followed by some descriptive text. For example: `US127175-message-positioning`.

Often times I know the ID but can't remember the descriptive text. Is there some way to do

```
git checkout US127175-*
```

and have it checkout `US127175-message-positioning`?

Comment: tab completion should do it, what shell are you using that doesn't do this?  I do `git checkout mas` and hit tab, it completes `master`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For local branches, as @jthill pointed out, tab completion usually does the trick. If not you can use grep:

```
git branch | grep <SEARCHTERM> | xargs git checkout
```

For remote branches:

```
git branch -r | grep <SEARCHTERM> | xargs git checkout
```

so for the example in the question:

```
git branch -r | grep US127175 | xargs git checkout
```

will checkout the remote branch `US127175-message-positioning`.

Comment: ...with the appropriate alias to use it more conveniently (here "cto" for "check this out" but whatever name of course) `git config --global alias.cto '!f() { git branch | grep $1 | xargs git checkout; }; f'` then just `git cto US127175`